# How to Backup and Restore System Drive in Windows7 Home Premium 64 bit

Tags: windows-7-backup

I am using Windows 7 home premium - 64 bit on Samsung laptop. I want to know that if there is any method or software available to backup the entire OS drive with all system settings and additional installed software.

My system has crashed few times and I have had to restore my OS to initial state and my software and settings are lost. I keep a lot of restore points but when restoring Windows these are unavailable.

Is there any way to backup and restore the entire system ("C") drive with all settings and additional installed software or is the backup provided by OS is suitable for this?

If possible please give steps for both backup and restore.

Comment: There are dozens of free and paid third-party programs that can do exactly this.  I will not suggest any specific program.

Comment: You are looking for "hdd imaging" or "hdd cloning" software. Linux has a tool called "dd", there is software for Windows too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a built in feature in Windows 7 to create a System Image you can access through the Backup and Restore option in the Control panel.
You will also have to creat a Repair Disk if you need to restore to a replacement disk.

See: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Back-up-your-programs-system-settings-and-files and
     http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/repair-recovery-help#repair-recovery-help=windows-7

It's somewhat more rudimentary than the third party applications you can buy.

Answer (score 0):

you will need some external media, like a usb mass storage disk. bigger than your HDD, then create one image of your entire disk. You can use Norton Ghost, as an example. There is a lot of software that can do what you want.

here you have an example using ghost.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBOuVC22hNA

Regards